# Iterate through a VB6 Dictionary

Tags: vb6, asp-classic, dictionary

I'm a non-VB6 person who had the misfortune of inheriting a buggy legacy VB6/Classic ASP project. There's a section where a lot of entries are put into a `Dictionary` and I want to see all it contains. I tried this (`oParams` is a Dictionary):

```
Dim o As Object
Dim sDicTempAggr As String
sDicTempAggr = ""
For Each o In oParams
    sDicTempAggr = sDicTempAggr & ", " & o
Next
```

Which returned:

> Object doesn't support this property or method : 438

Using `Option Explicit`, how do I iterate through a VB6 `Dictionary` to find out everything it contains?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a sample for iterating, if you still have a problem look at the second loop to inspect the types of the values in the dictionary

```
  Dim oParams As New Dictionary
    oParams.Add 1, "This"
    oParams.Add 2, "That"
    oParams.Add 3, "The other"
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim sDicTempAggr  As String
    Dim sTypes As String
    For Each key In oParams.Keys
        sDicTempAggr = sDicTempAggr & IIf(sDicTempAggr <> "", ",", "") & oParams(key)
    Next key
    For Each key In oParams.Keys
          sTypes = sTypes & IIf(sTypes <> "", ",", "") & TypeName(oParams(key))
    Next key
```

Answer (score 10):

An enumeration over a Dictionary isn't of type `Object`, you should use `Variant` instead:

```
Dim o As Variant
Dim sDicTempAggr As String
sDicTempAggr = ""

For Each o In oParams
    sDicTempAggr = sDicTempAggr & ", " & oParams(o)
Next
```

Also within the `For Each` the Key is returned not the dictionary member hence the `oParams(o)` for the value, if you change to For `Each o In oParams.items` you can use `oParams` directly.