# Passing Dictionary Object from Classic ASP to C#

Tags: c#, com, asp-classic

i'm calling a C# com interop dll from classic asp.

i want to send name value pairs to the c# dll.

tried using dictionary object in classic asp and accepting it using the same dictionary object (scripting.runtime com reference) in C#.

But it gives Invalid procedure call or argument error.

I got this idea of using scripting.dictionary from this link
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10016705/is-there-any-way-to-pass-a-dictionary-object-to-c.aspx

may be im missing something

**Questions**

1. am i missing something or is there a better way to pass key value
   pairs from Classic asp to C#.
2. i'm also considering using this library asp3tojson and
   deserializing in C#. is it too complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd convert it to JSON. At least to know there are no object-level interoperability problems, especially when it comes to mixing in various MS objects.

Comment: Can you suggest a good library to convert classic asp dictionary object to json. The asp3json doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: You'll probably have to loop through the dictionary and build up the JSON as a string. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789830/iterate-through-a-vb6-dictionary

Comment: Here is a classic ASP JSON utility library: http://www.webdevbros.net/2008/07/10/asp-json-utility-version-15-released/

Answer (score 1):

Hi. It's possible to use **System.Collections.HashTable** (*and many other from mscorlib*) within asp classic applications.
Try the following. Hopefully useful.
**Asp App:**

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim Dictionary, objNetCom, i

Set Dictionary  = Server.CreateObject("System.Collections.HashTable")
Set objNetCom   = Server.CreateObject("MyTest.doTest")

With Dictionary
    For i = 65 To 90
        .Add Chr(i), i 
    Next
End With
Response.Write objNetCom.getDictType(Dictionary) 

Set Dictionary  = Nothing
Set objNetCom   = Nothing
```

**a c# Com Visible:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace MyTest
{
    public class doTest
    {
        public string getDictType(Object tDict)
        {
            return String.Format("Type : \"{0}\", Count : {1}", ((Hashtable)tDict).GetType().ToString(), ((Hashtable)tDict).Count);
        }
    }
}
```