# How to iterate dictionary?

Tags: vb6

I am trying to iterate through dictionary but encounter the error "Object required". The related code is given below.

First, I create a dictionary.

```
Dim customers
Set customers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

I also define class of "cCustomer", then use the dictionary like this.

```
Set customer = New cCustomer
customer.Init location, first, last
customers.Add location, customer
```

Then I use "For Each" to iterate.

```
Dim cc
For Each cc in customers.items
  ...
Next
```

This is OK. But I really want to declare "cc" with type.

```
Dim cc As cCustomer
```

But if I do this, VB runtime complains "Object required" at the line of "For Each". I think it is somehow related to the missing of type declaration when creating the dictionary? I am still new to VB. Thanks for the help.

MORE: why this is not duplicate...

I have tried the solution suggested by the link, namely, (a) using Dictionary instead of "Scripting.Dictionary", and (b) "Dim cc As Variant". It works as before but if I feed "cc" into a function whose argument has specific type it still fails.

```
Public Function foo(customer As cCustomer) As String
  ...
End Function

Dim cc As Variant
For Each cc in customers.items
  foo(cc)
Next
```

The error is "ByRef argument type mismatch".

That's the reason I really need to declare "cc" as "cCustomer", but it has error of "Object required".

```
Dim cc As cCustomer
For Each cc In customers.items
  ...
```

Per comments

- tried "Dim cc As Object", doesn't work ("Object required").
- tried "remove Dim cc", doesn't work either ("ByRef argument type mismatch").

I could do "ByVal" in the function definition or use another variable, but that would involve extra copy. Something like type casting might help...

Comment: Have you tried changing it to just `for each cc in customers` ?
Also, make sure that custmers definitley is initalized in the scope of the `for each` loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through a VB6 Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789830/iterate-through-a-vb6-dictionary)

Comment: if you leave off the type in VB6/sbscript it will be a Variant, not an Object. You could try to change your declaration to  " As Object". also, any reason you are using CreateObject? It's better to include the library, and use the Dictionary type directly, because you'll get a bit of intellisense, and errors may get caught sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of a cludge and there may be better ways of doing it, but how about this:

```
dim loc as variant
dim cc as cCustomer

for each loc in Customers
    set cc = Customers(loc)
    foo(cc)
next loc
```

It may even be possible to do `foo (Customers(loc))`, but I suspect you will get the type mismatch error again. I don't think you can pass an object with `byval`

Comment: Thanks, let to inform that this question is more VB6-specific and I move on to VB.net, which is much less painful in this regard.